# What does "out" mean after words?

Tags: meaning

What does "out" mean after words?

**"work out"** 
**"check out"**
**"point out"**

Comment: Each is a separate idiom, with likely a separate origin.

Comment: True, they are idioms, like most phrasal verbs. Still, there is a generic sense of "to completion" with many _out_ constructions. _Work out the problem_ means 'solve the problem', _check out the acceleration_ means 'notice the acceleration', _point out the mistake_ means 'identify the mistake'. Each of these refer to some action carried to completion, or at least to the next step in its completion.

Comment: @JohnLawler, that looks like an answer, not a comment.